# $a^b = c$, is it possible to express $b$ without logarithms?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

$ a^b = c $

is it possible to express b without logarithms?

Comment: Not in general.  Sometimes you can get lucky but, in general, you need a logarithmic expression.

Comment: The logarithm is defined to solve this kind of problems. This feels like asking, "If $a+b=c$, is it possible to express $b$ without subtraction?" Of course if $2^x=4$ then $x=2$, say, but in general, we have no nice way of getting it but writing $b=\log_a c$.

Comment: one thing you could do is expressing $\log_{a }{ c}$  as a power series to get rid of the logarithmic expression in your equation , but those are just unnecessary complications

Comment: It would be kind of pointless, since $\log_a(c)$ is *defined* as the value $b$ such that $a^b=c$. So any other expression for $b$ is just another expression for the logarithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without more information, since finding $b$ in this case is what logarithms are.  Maybe in some special cases something can be said.

Answer (score 0):

If $e^b=c$, then $b=\ln c$.  Is it possible to express $\ln c$ without logarithms?  Not unless you have a peculiar definition of "without"...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, certainly not the most practical though.

$5^{3x}=\dfrac{1}{125}$

$5^{3x}=\dfrac{1}{5^3}$

$5^{3x}=5^{-3}$

$3x=-3$

$\dfrac{3x}{3}=\dfrac{-3}{3}$

$\boxed{x=-1}$